# Querying against a number type field does not work correctly

Tags: mongodb

I have a field which is of type number,

> typeof db.grants.findOne().approvalfy 
>   number

When i query the database on this field against a number I dont get the correct results

> db.grants.find({approvalfy:{$gt:2013}},{regionname:true,approvalfy:true}).count() 
>   1

however when I query the field against a string, i get the correct results.

> db.grants.find({approvalfy:{$gt:"2013"}},{regionname:true,approvalfy:true}).count() 
>   66

Can somebody please explain this?

Comment: Does that first bit of code define the schema? What framework is that?

Comment: @RobertMoskal, I ran that command to check the type of field (to make sure that it is a number). I am running these commands in the mongodb shell

Comment: Why do you think all values are numeric? They are in fact being confirmed to in fact be "strings" by the query. All the statement `typeof db.grants.findOne().approvalfy ` is actually telling you is that the **first** document found happens to have a numeric value. This is also confirmed by your `.count()` when testing with a numeric value, in that only **one** is actually found. All you really need do is simply look at the data in the shell as `2013` will look visibly different to `"2013"` ( note the quotes `""` ).

Comment: You can also query with [`$type`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/) as in `db.grants.find({ "approvalfy": { "$type": 2 } })` for "string", and "likely" `db.grants.find({ "approvalfy": { "$type": 1 } })` for the numeric, where the default "double", or otherwise of "type" `16` or `18` or even possibly `19` all as documented. So if you expect numeric, then you must convert the data as such.

Comment: Thanks @NeilLunn, I do realize now that there are mixed types for the same attribute.

Answer (score 0):

As @NeilLunn has pointed it, the attribute that I am querying has both numeric and string data. The combination of these two datatypes leads to the results that I got earlier